# WSO2 Data Service Server - Adding a Custom Data Source

Tags: mongodb, wso2-data-services-server

Can anyone help me on how to configure/create a Custom Data Source and using WSO2 4.0.2

Here is a sample wso2-dss-connector for Mongo DB ( Link : https://github.com/wso2/wso2-dss-connectors/tree/master/mongodb) . How to deploy this with WSO2. While building this project,we can get a jar ,so how to integrate this with wso2 for creating a custom datasource

I am new to wso2,i didn't get a clear picture from the official doc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want a connector for mongo db you can use the above link you mentioned and build this jar and you can put this in the DSSHOME/repository/component/dropins folder and restart the server. Once you have added the jar to dropins you can use the [following database descriptor file](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-dss-connectors/blob/master/mongodb/samples/MongoSampleDS.dbs) (dbs) to test this

In this example we create a data source call "mongo_ds" and our query will be called mongo_find, which will retreive set of Documents elements.

```
 <config id="mongo_ds">
      <property name="custom_query_datasource_class">org.wso2.dss.connectors.mongodb.MongoDBDataSource</property>
      <property name="custom_datasource_props">
         <property name="servers">localhost</property>
         <property name="database">mydb</property>
      </property>
   </config>
   <query id="mongo_find" useConfig="mongo_ds">
      <expression>things.find()</expression>
      <result element="Documents" rowName="Document">
         <element column="document" name="Data" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
   </query>
```

If you want to write custom data sources for other data sources please refer the [following guide.](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS311/Configuring+a+Custom+Datasource)